# How to cross validate by using Encog?

Tags: c#, encog, neat

There are no articles about corss-validation and the way of getting network weights after training by using NEAT in Encog. I really apreciate it if someone could give me how to do that.

Comment: I have my NEAT trained on custom `CalculateScore` function of `ICalculateScore class` hence, in my case I simply cross-validate by observing the score on unseen data.

Comment: Many thanks for giving me useful advice. But the cross-validation I mentioned above is "K-fold cross validation" method. I have no idea how to execute k-fold cross validation in NEAT with encog. I've never  found out any sample code on this. I really appreciate it if someone could give me the sample code on this.